# Implementing Github like network graph

Tags: reactjs, git, github, web

I am trying to implement Github like network graph in a React app for my next project. The basic idea is to fetch commits in a repo through Github API (sample response: https://api.github.com/repos/Samarthya2912/dummy-repo/commits) and use it to create a network graph.

I have been able to come up with a solution that can do the same using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@antv/g6 which renders the required graph given the x and y coordinates of commits. I wrote a very basic code to compute for a relatively simpler history.

```
const x = 100, y = 100;
    const dx = 150, dy = 170;

    let coordinates = {};
    coordinates[root] = [x, y];

    let queue = [root];

    while (queue.length > 0) {
        let current = queue.shift();
        let [x, y] = coordinates[current];

        if (graph[current].length === 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (graph[current].length === 1) {
            let child = graph[current][0];
            coordinates[child] = [x + dx, y];
            queue.push(child);
        } else if (graph[current].length === 2) {
            let [child1, child2] = graph[current];
            coordinates[child1] = [x + dx, y];
            coordinates[child2] = [x + dx, y + dy];
            queue.push(child1);
            queue.push(child2);
        }
    }
```

[image: Attempt]

But a more advanced function is needed for a repo with multiple merges and branches. Is there a better implementation for this?

Answer (score 1):

For a more complex history graph, you can refer to [`initialcommit-com/git-sim`](https://github.com/initialcommit-com/git-sim) ([requires Python](https://pypi.org/project/git-sim/))

It is [presented here](https://initialcommit.com/tools/git-sim) and [illustrated here](https://initialcommit.com/blog/git-sim)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49353917/210942030-c7229488-571a-4943-a1f4-c6e4a0c8ccf3.jpg]

Comment: I understand that this generates an image but I want individual commit points be clickable so I am looking for a more canvas oriented approach. Moreover if you can point to the alogirthm being used to decide the points of rendering commit points used in the above.

Comment: @SamarthyaSingh This is more an animation setup, as [illustrated here](https://github.com/initialcommit-com/git-sim/blob/cc116cbb8d250f7f2fd0d3183e6c2965f5821fd3/git_sim/cherrypick.py#L53-L70).